# SSIS Send Mail Task - passing an expression in a variable

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a **ScriptTask** that assigns values of nodes from an XML email template to SSIS package variables. I then use those variables in a **SendMailTask**. In the **SendMailTask**, when I create the following expression for the **MessageSource** field:

```
"There was an error in processing order #" + @[User::ErrorOrderId] + " for the vendor " + @[User::ErrorVendorName]  + "."
```

I get the result in the email body:

```
There was an error in processing order #000000 for the vendor Acme.
```

This is the output that I want. But when I add the same expression to an XML email template, and in a **ScriptTask** assign that expression to the variable  **@[User::EmailErrorMessage]**. In the **SendMailTask** Expression I assign the **MessageSource** field that variable, the output in the email is the string literal without and parameters being replaced:

```
"There was an error in processing order #" + @[User::ErrorOrderId] + " for the vendor " + @[User::ErrorVendorName]  + "."
```

My question is, is there a way to pass an SSIS Expression as a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the EvaluateAsExpression property to True on the variable you're assigning to @[User::EmailErrorMessage].  (Select the variable in the Variables window and then check the Properties window.)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @Skerkles!!